# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object using laravel 6

Tags: arrays, laravel

I want return an `array` to show it in a `datatable` and also in `callendar5`, but it gives me an error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\agendab\resources\views\index .blade.php).

I filled `array` `$events` with `$bookings` returned in `controller`, and I want it show in `index.blade.php` when I do dd($events) it returns array, see image:

[image: image array return]

**EventController.php**

```
$events = array();
$bookings = Event::all();

foreach($bookings as $booking) {
    $color = null;
    $events[] = [
        'id'   => $booking->id,
        'titre' => $booking->name,
        'start' => $booking->datee,
        'comment' => $booking->comment,
        'color' => $color
    ];
}

$users  = User::all();
return view('index')->with([
    'events'     => $events,
    'users'       => $users,
]);
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($events as $event)
    <tr id="{{$event->id}}">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="customer_id[]" value="{{$event->id}}" /></td>
        <td>{{ $event->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $event->datee }}</td>
        <td>{{ $event->name }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ $event->comment }}
                <a href="#" target='_blank' class=""> <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                </a>
        </td>
            <th scope="col">{{ Str::upper( $event->user->name) }}</th>
        <td>
            <span class="badge badge-warning">{{ $event->status }}</span>
            
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\agendab\resources\views\index.blade.php).

Exception messages are pretty handy for locating problems, the one you're seeing (above) is telling you which file the exception originates from. In this case it is it your `index.blade.php` view file.

Within that file you're iterating (looping) over your `$events`:

```
@foreach($events as $event)

{{-- doing stuff here --}}

@endforeach
```

The problem occurs because of how you're trying to access data within the iterated `$event` variable. You're accessing data as if `$event` is an `object` using the object operator (`->`) however, in your `Controller` you're populating `$events` as an array:

```
$events[] = [
    'id'   => $booking->id,
    'titre' => $booking->name,
    'start' => $booking->datee,
    'comment' => $booking->comment,
    'color' => $color
];
```

So in your `index.blade.php` view, you need to access the data of `$events` using the `array` syntax:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($events as $event)
    <tr id="{{ $event['id'] }}">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="customer_id[]" value="{{ $event['id'] }}" /></td>
        <td>{{ $event['id'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $event['start'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $event['name'] }}</td>
        {{-- etc. --}}
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Note that you will still need to sort out other errors in your code. For example you're not adding a `name` element to your `$events[]` array in your controller but you're trying to access it in your view.

There are other errors that you will need to resolve too, but the above will fix the immediate issue you've asked about.